# Depth of the IBM MQ

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq, pcf

Can you please help me, I am trying to find the ibm mq depth with PCFAgent over SSL channel.

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
     Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","abc-dev.jks");
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","abcdabcd");

     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "abc-dev.jks");
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "abcdabcd");

     MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA";



    int attrs[] = { 2016, 3 };
    System.out.println("parameter creation");
    PCFParameter parameters[] = { new MQCFST(2016, "*"), new MQCFIN(20, 1),
            new MQCFIL(1002, attrs) };
    String name = null;
    Integer depth = null;
    System.out.println("parameter creation end");



    try {
        PCFAgent agent;
        if (args.length == 1) {
            System.out.print("Connecting to local queue manager " + args[0]
                    + "... ");
            agent = new PCFAgent(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Connecting to queue manager at " + args[0]
                    + ":" + args[1] + " over channel " + args[2] + "... ");
            agent = new PCFAgent(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
                    args[2]);
        }
        System.out.println("Connected.");
        System.out.print("Sending PCF request... ");
        com.ibm.mq.MQMessage responses[] = agent.send(13, parameters);
        System.out.println("Received reply.");
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            MQCFH cfh = new MQCFH(responses[i]);
            if (cfh.reason == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cfh.parameterCount; j++) {
                    PCFParameter p = PCFParameter
                            .nextParameter(responses[i]);
                    switch (p.getParameter()) {
                    case 2016:
                        name = (String) p.getValue();
                        break;

                    case 3: // '\003'
                        depth = (Integer) p.getValue();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Queue " + name + " curdepth " + depth);
            } else {
                System.out.println("PCF error:\n" + cfh);
                for (int j = 0; j < cfh.parameterCount; j++)
                    System.out.println(PCFParameter
                            .nextParameter(responses[0]));

            }
        }

        System.out.print("Disconnecting... ");
        agent.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException abe) {
        System.out
                .println("Usage: \n\tjava ListQueueDepth queue-manager\n\tjava ListQueueDepth host port channel");
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Invalid port: " + args[1]);
        System.out
                .println("Usage: \n\tjava ListQueueDepth queue-manager\n\tjava ListQueueDepth host port channel");
    } catch (MQException mqe) {
        System.err.println(mqe);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println(ioe);
    }
```

When I try run this program remotely, I am getting the following exception:

> com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2035

**EDIT to add additional clarifying details from the comments:**

The MQ Admin found an error in the `AMQERR01.LOG` related to the  SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE at the same time the application receives the 2035.

The same program works for a non-SSL channel when I take off the security settings and ciphersuite.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't see where you set a UserID in the code.  Therefore, you are sending a blank UserID which if the channel's MCAUSER is blank means, it becomes 'mqm' UserID because of an old security hole.

For MQ v7.1 or higher, the default CHLAUTH rule will block the connection if you are on a 'SYSTEM' channel.  Or for MQ v8.0 or higher, the channel may require a UserID and Password.  You need to look at either the event queue or queue manager logs for the reason for the RC of 2035 (not authorized).

```
int attrs[] = { 2016, 3 };
PCFParameter parameters[] = { new MQCFST(2016, "*"),
                              new MQCFIN(20, 1),
                              new MQCFIL(1002, attrs) };
```

Also, what is with the hard-coded values?  Did you decompile someone else's program?

Why aren't you using the IBM MQ supplied defines?  Here's what it should look like:

```
int[] attrs = {
                CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME,
                CMQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH
              };
PCFParameter[] parameters = {
                               new MQCFST (CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*"),
                               new MQCFIN (CMQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, CMQC.MQQT_LOCAL),
                               new MQCFIL (CMQCFC.MQIACF_Q_ATTRS, attrs)
                            };
```

Comment: Is it only for the SSL channel that I need to set the UserID and Password? Because the same program works for non-SSL channel when I take off the security settings and ciphersuite. If it is because it is an SSL channel, please let me know what UserID and Password I need to set here?

Comment: What do you see in the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG when your client receives the 2035 response?

Comment: Hi, I do not have access to those logs. All that I have is the 2035 error.

Comment: You would need to ask the MQ admin who has access to provide that information.  There are many different reasons you may be getting the 2035 error and without the information from the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` you can't tell what the specific reason is.  Please update your question with details from the MQ queue manager logs.

Comment: MQ Admin says there is an error in SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE. He was asking if I was creating a dynamic queue. I am not sure about that. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The `PCFAgent` class creates a dynamic queue for the response messages from the command server.  By default the model queue used is `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE`.  The user needs to have OAM permission `+get +dsp` on the model queue.

If the program works when connecting to a non-SSL channel then the connection must be resolving to a different userid that has the required OAM permission against the `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE`.

The error in the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` would show the userid that is missing the permission(s) along with the the specific permission(s) missing.

Depending on what version of MQ client jar files you are using, if you do not specify a UserID the MQ client will either send blank UserID or the UserID the java process is running under. On the queue manager side if the `MCAUSER` attribute of the channel is blank, then it would inherit either mqm if a blank UserID was received or the UserID your process is running under. If the `MCAUSER` attribute of the channel is not blank that is the UserID that will be used for permission.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to know what user are you talking about here? Because we are passing any UserId in the code right.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the entry the MQ Admin found in the AMQERR01.LOG, this should show both the userid that is missing permission and what permission it is missing.  It would also be helpful to see the following display commands of both the ssl and non-ssl channels: `DIS CHL(CHL.NAME) MCAUSER` and `DIS CHLAUTH(CHL.NAME)`.  Please sanitize the information as you feel appropriate. I can update my answer with more detail about the username each channel would resolve to based on the additional detail.

Comment: Hi Josh, Admin says that I am not supposed to use PCF messages due to some security concerns. Is there any other way that I can find the queue depth?

Comment: @Prakash that would be a new question, you should accept an answer here based on the original question you asked and post a new question regarding how to  find queue depth from MQ Java API that does not rely on PCF messages.

Comment: Sure Josh. I will do that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Prakash (last seen March 3 2017), if you ever come back please click the check mark to accept my answer.